search words in english and persian with or without special charachter (not imprtant) as a sentence not single word
here is my code :
$data = file_get_contents($row['source_link']);                 
                
$regex = '/ '.$row["word_match"].'/';   

preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match);
echo $match[1];

My problem is that this code only finds single words in English or Persian. I need it to find English plus Persian, numbers, and special characters (special characters can be optional) in one sentence.
For example:
گوشی موبایل Samsung مدل Galaxy A15 (RAM 4) ظرفیت 128GB - سرمه ای (ویتنام)

Here are some examples:
Input: سرمه ای (ویتنام) گوشی موبایل
Output:
array(0) {}


Input: ویتنام
Output:
array(1) {
    [0]=> string(13) " ویتنام"
}   


What is the structure of your file? Are items separated by new lines or something else? When you search for "ویتنام", what result do you need? Is it گوشی موبایل Samsung مدل Galaxy A15 (RAM 4) ظرفیت 128GB - سرمه ای (ویتنام)?

they separeted with space mostly

my problem is when i serach a sentence or spacial charachters no results find.this simple search engine only can find simple words

possibly related: Are the PHP preg_functions multibyte safe?
